# Database for storing contracts: mysql + php, handling numbered items in database design

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for solutions to store the contracts in the database. I use mysql + php. A contract looks like this

Contract #`place holder`

place `place holder` date `place holder`

1. GENERAL TERMS

1.1. text-text-text `place holder` text-text-text

...

2. FINANCIAL TERMS

2.1. text-text-text `place holder`

and so on.

The things to be put instead of the `place holder`s will come a DB query.

My first idea is to create 3 tables (simplified): 1st with contract numbers, 2nd with numbered items (1, 1.1, ... 2, 2.1, ...) and textual fields relating to the numbered items, and 3rd having many-to-many relationship between the 1st and the 2nd table. I'm afraid that this solution is a nightmare to maintain because the textual fields can change, some may be left out completely depending on the contract.

What are the possible solutions to my problem? One thing to keep in mind is that I want to display the contract in the html later, or maybe in a Word document, whatever is easier.

Comment: My comment will be of no help but perhaps you have fun [reading this](https://github.com/Droogans/unmaintainable-code#on-the-proper-use-of-design-documents). The guy introduced functions based on the chapter's numbers of the specification document, like `function_1_3_7_4_16()` to implement the behaviour given in chapter 1.3.7.4.16. _YES_, this will be a nightmare.

Comment: haha, loved the subtitle of the whole thing "Ensure a job for life ;-)" real nice. thanks, buddy! lifted the mood.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :-) I _know_ your first idea is, well, not the best but I'm afraid I have no better one right now. Some kind of IDs for the chapters would be of help. Actually the contracts are a mash-up of text templates each of which should have an ID. Then you can tell "contract X is made up of textblock a, b, and c". It won't be that easy; sometimes order matters as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the internet and trials + errors, replacement of place holders for the needed data from the DB is not a problem (obviously). The problem is how to get the numbered items from the database and not have a DB design nightmare. In the end, decided to go with one TEXTual field in mysql that stores the complete text of the contract. Then use something like http://parsedown.org/ that'll format the numbered items well. Then the person who's not familiar with the html markup can correct the contract text if necessary, and Parsedown (or similar) will take care of the proper html layout.